# How to talk about a commute?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

**A) Which of the following sentences are idiomatic and grammatical?**

**B) Is it necessary to say "every day" if I used "commute"?**

> 1) It's 30-minute commute to my work every day.
>
> 2) I commute to my work in 30 minutes every day.
>
> 3) I drive 30 minutes to work every day.
>
> 4) I commute to work by my private car for 30 minutes every day.
>
> 5) My commute to work takes 30 minutes every day.

Comment: You could say "my daily commute". Some people work away from home and commute weekly. If you want to omit something, leave out "to work". So "My daily commute takes 30 minutes."

Comment: When you compare *idiomatic* to *ungrammatical* you are comparing apples to oranges. Something can be idiomatic without being grammatical, and something else can be unidiomatic despite being grammatical.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with using the word *commute* and not mentioning *every day* (or any other time period).